# Restrict firebase database to make new nodes using firebase rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, rules

How can i restrict database to make any new nodes(from an app) in the database using firebase rules.

My database looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have wrote rule for all the existing nodes in database, after that write the following rule for preventing creation of new nodes from android app or any other integration

```
  "rules": {
    "Articles": {
        ".read": //rules that you want to write
        ".write": //rules that you want to write
    }
    "Categories": {
        ".read": //rules that you want to write
        ".write": //rules that you want to write
    }
    .
    .
    //rules for other nodes in your database
    .
    .
    "$NewNode":{
        //This rule will prevent from creating new nodes
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to write one rule for all "existing" nodes?  Because there will be too many nodes in the future also. like i want to do is read/write true to all existing nodes,and read/write false to any newly made node.

Comment: You can write it one rule in single line if the current nodes and future nodes will have same security, so the above method is recommended cause it allows you to have separate rule for each node and easy to manage and scale in future

Comment: Can i make one rule for all the existing nodes?means defining a rule for articles.exercises,quizzes all at once?And yes you are right,your approach is good.But if theres any way to do all define a rule for all pre-made nodes.